# CRON TAB working fine for */15 but not working for 12/15

Tags: cron

My cron job is working fine if I write

*/15 16 * * * setup.sh

It is called cron job at every 15th minute like 0,15,30,45 and again 0.

I need to run 15th minute of a specific time

Ex:  crontab(12)

12/15 16 * * *

This is correct by https://crontab.guru/ but showing a non-standard cron job may not work on some crontab.
And also not working in my case.

Help me to sort it out. Thanks in advance

Comment: `15 16 * * *` will make it run at 4:15pm every day.

Answer (score 0):

The "12/" part is what makes it non-standard.

You could rewrite it as:

```
12,27,42,57 16 * * *
```

And that should work.